# Shopware 6 Plugin: Update function not saving config values

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a Shopware 6 plugin that contains an update function to migrate some config values on upgrade:

```php
    public function update(UpdateContext $context): void {
        parent::update($context);
        
        // Get the currently installed version
        $version = $context->getCurrentPluginVersion(); 

        // Only update config if on version 1.7.3 or higher
        if (version_compare($version, '1.7.3', '>=')) {
            // Get config service from the container
            $configService = $this->container->get('Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService');       
        
            // Get the current value of the configuration
            $previousConfigVal  = $configService->getBool('SwagPlugin.config.reviewSkipModeration');
            $newConfigVal = $previousConfigVal ? '0' : 'None';
               
            // Set the specified value as default
            $configService->set('SwagPlugin.config.autoPublishStars', $newConfigVal);    
        }
    }
```

During my tests, this code runs without errors on plugin upgrade in the past. However, currently after the update, the new config value is not saved or persisted.

When I update the config field is not created in DB at all. If I directly install a plugin version greater than 1.7.3. Then there is a config field.

```xml
       <input-field type="bool">
            <name>reviewSkipModeration</name>
            <label>Accept reviews automatically</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Bewertungen automatisch freigeschaltet</label>
            <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
        </input-field>
        <input-field type="single-select">
            <name>autoPublishStars</name>
            <label>Auto Publish review with stars</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Sterne vorausgewählt</label>
            <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
            <options>
                <option>
                    <id>None</id>
                    <name>None</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">Keine</name>
                </option>                
                <option>
                    <id>0</id>
                    <name>0 Star</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">0 Stern</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>1 Star</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">1 Stern</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <name>2 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">2 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <name>3 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">3 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>4</id>
                    <name>4 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">4 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <name>5 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">5 Sterne</name>
                </option>
            </options>
        </input-field>
```

Thats what I see now.
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.